# Read existing property using spring profiles

Tags: spring, spring-3

To read a Spring profile I use :

```
<beans profile="LOC">
```

I have this property set as a jvm property :

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=LOC
```

I would like to use an existing property instead which is already configured :

```
-Dmyproperty=LOC
```

Can I use spring profiles to use the existing property (`myproperty`) instead of `spring.profiles.active` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [source code of spring-core.jar AbstractEnvironment.java](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework/blob/7e0157851553f048443fcf48fa920b59970ca43c/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/env/AbstractEnvironment.java) class. The system property name is hardcoded here:

```
   /**
     * Name of property to set to specify active profiles: {@value}. Value may be comma
     * delimited.
     * <p>Note that certain shell environments such as Bash disallow the use of the period
     * character in variable names. Assuming that Spring's {@link SystemEnvironmentPropertySource}
     * is in use, this property may be specified as an environment variable as
     * {@code SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE}.
     * @see ConfigurableEnvironment#setActiveProfiles
     */
    public static final String ACTIVE_PROFILES_PROPERTY_NAME = "spring.profiles.active";
```

So yes you can hack it and change it to your property name, or make it configurable and recompile your own version (kids please don't try this at home).